# Cookies not being stored

Tags: javascript, cookies

So I am quite new to cookies and I was wondering why this doesn't work to read cookie data?

```
//How to sort through the cookies
document.cookie = "key1=value1; key2=value2";
console.log(document.cookie);
//Makes an array of the Cookies
let pairs = document.cookie.split(";");
//Dictionary
let cookieDictionary={};

//Loops through the cookies and assigns them to a dictionary.
for(p of pairs)
{
    let vals = p.split("=");
    cookieDictionary[vals[0]] = vals[1];
}
//Create a key for easy cookie lookup
let cookieKeys = Object.keys(cookieDictionary);
console.log(cookieKeys);
```

Comment: It seems to read the cookies fine. The problem is how you are setting them.

Comment: What is the issue with the way that I am setting them so I can improve it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can only set one cookie at the time

So instead of

```
document.cookie = "key1=value1; key2=value2";
```

you should be doing

```
document.cookie = "key1=value1";
document.cookie = "key2=value2";
```

The entire script should then be something like

```
//How to sort through the cookies
document.cookie = "key1=value1"; 
document.cookie = "key2=value2";


console.log(document.cookie);
//Makes an array of the Cookies
let pairs = document.cookie.split(";");
//Dictionary
let cookieDictionary={};

//Loops through the cookies and assigns them to a dictionary.
for(p of pairs)
{
    let vals = p.split("=");
    cookieDictionary[vals[0]] = vals[1];
}
//Create a key for easy cookie lookup
let cookieKeys = Object.keys(cookieDictionary);
console.log(cookieKeys);
```

Like in this jsfiddle https://jsfiddle.net/tzr5b6s4/1/

MDN: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/cookie

And there is a really nice SO post here [Set cookie and get cookie with JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14573223/set-cookie-and-get-cookie-with-javascript)

Comment: So I tried doing that, but when using console.log to see the keys of the cookies, the array is still empty.

Comment: Take a look at the fiddle in the updated answer, it works as expected

Comment: Oh now I see it, I was having a cors issue. Once I opened it on localhost it worked! Thank you so much!!